# The distribution of the square of a Student's t-distributed random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, t-distribution

The following may not be very difficult, but I'm struggling to get started.

$T_k = \frac{Z_0}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{k}(Z_1^2 + \dots + Z_k^2)}}$, where $Z_0, \dots$ are i.i.d. standard normal random variables, is a random variable following the Student's $t$-distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom. How do you calculate $P(T_k^2 \leq x)$?

All I've observed so far is that squaring the fraction results in a $\chi^2(1)$-distributed RV divided by a $\chi^2(k)$-distributed RV (there's also the multiplication by $k$, but I don't think that's essential for now).

Comment: The ratio of two $\chi^2$ variates is linked with a well known distribution

Comment: I browsed the Wikipedia entry on ratio distributions and then clicked on a link to the F-distribution. I suppose I can follow the derivation of the density [here](https://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/pdfc-fdist.htm) with $m = 1, n = k$.